# Question on filing form 8606 for tax year 2020

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, irs

I am filling [form 8606 for tax year 2020](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f8606--2020.pdf) and have below question:

**Line 8**:

> Enter the net amount you converted from traditional, SEP, and SIMPLE
> IRAs to Roth IRAs in 2020. Also, enter this amount on line 16

Does this mean only amount converted between till **December 31,2020** or till tax due date **April 15,2021**?

I converted few dollars from traditional IRA to Roth IRA after 12/31/2020 but before 04/15/2021 so confused if I need to include that or not.

I am following [Instructions for Form 8606](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/i8606--2020.pdf) as well but still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why it is confusing. "In 2020" means between January 1st, 2020 and December 31st, 2020.

Your conversion was completed after December 31st, 2020, and as such is not included in this time range.

Comment: To explain a possible confusion: you can make IRA _contributions_ for year Y until April 15 of Y+1 (or next business day) (assuming you are eligible to contribute at all, i.e. have 'compensation') and lots of web pages, advertisements, etc. promote/encourage doing this, but you can only do _conversions_ -- or distributions -- for Y until Dec. 31 of Y, except that you can correct an excess contribution until April 15 (or recharacterize until Oct. 15). RMDs have a different quirk; your _first_ RMD can be until April 1 (NOT 15) of Y+1, but all subsequent ones must be by Dec. 31 of Y.

Comment: (But you can no longer undo a conversion in Y by recharacterizing in Y+1 up to Oct. 15; that trick was repealed by IIRC TCJA.)